# Why does adding types to my Julia function cause a MethodError?

Tags: julia

I'm migrating from Python and am pretty new to Julia, but this one is proving pretty difficult to figure out. I'm hoping to later compile packages via PackageCompiler for later use in other languages, so I need to able to export C callable methods. If I define the following code:

```
module MyModule

export testmethod1
export testmethod2

function testmethod1(x::Cfloat, y::Cfloat)::Cfloat
    return x^y*4
end

function testmethod2(x, y)
    return x^y*4
end

end
```

And call `println(MyModule.testmethod2(2.3, 3.2))`, I get `57.489570831681995`

However, when I call `println(MyModule.testmethod1(2.3, 3.2))`, I get

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching testmethod1(::Float64, ::Float64)
```

But when I type check these variables, say, `println(typeof(2.3))`, I get `Float64`! Why is Julia unable to match the input I am giving to the function when I specify Cfloat as the data type?

Comment: `Cfloat` is a `Float32` `2.3` is a `Float64`.

Comment: Well I feel dumb. The matching was for the type of the function I tried to call rather than the one that existed. Will you put this as an answer, or is it more along the lines of SO etiquette to have this as a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cfloat` is a `Float32` `2.3` is a `Float64`. Note that you probably shouln't be using `Cfloat` (or other types that are `C`+type) frequently. Those are aliases for C interop.